# Best practice for Database migration in test , production server in asp.net core 2.0 + app

Tags: c#, .net-core, production-environment, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I am working on a new project which is in asp.net 2.1 web API 
here I am using Code first migration in local DB

so to deploy my app to test environment I need to know 
best and safe practice for database migration because this is a new project and in the future daily base there will be a lot of changes may occur

Comment: Is your test environment local or hosted? Are you looking to migrate all data added or just apply the missing migrations?

Comment: this will host to server  and migration should be mature to like automatic configure means if we need to switch to production server will be safe

Comment: as research for automate migrator I had find https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator
and available in NuGet package and support dotnet core

Answer (score 2):

Well it sounds like you are mixing migration with deployment.
Migration with Code First means making changes in your Data model.
Deploying your code or database to Production is something different.
I assume you are referring to deployment in your question.
Best way of deployment for both applications and databases is to automate it.
Jenkins, TFS, Teamcity , Octopus are some of the popular CD tools.
To automate the database deployment you need to write custom libraries.
In one of the companies I worked we check in the DDL script to source code and automated build library drops all the stored procs, functions . Runs the ddl script and re-creates all the stored procs,functions. 
This way we can be 100% sure all the Environments(QA,Staging, Prod)  are in sync .

Comment: ok this is good and have you tried NuGet  package fluentmigrator ?

Answer (score 1):

[**Best practices are actually provided by Microsoft here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implemenation-entity-framework-core)

Apart from that, [this repository](https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject/) provides a good enterprise-level example of how .NET Core Web App/API projects should be written and describes the following practices that help the project scale reliably as the project size grows. It is also updated regularly.

1. Full architecture with responsibility separation concerns, SOLID and
   Clean Code
2. Domain Driven Design (Layers and Domain Model Pattern)
3. Domain Events
4. Domain Notification
5. CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation)
6. Event Sourcing
7. Unit of Work Repository and Generic Repository